# How to organize page1/page2/pageN paging with GAE?

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

How can I understand which page user is looking for, if they should be defined in the url like:

```
http://mysite.appspot.com/something/something-else/      - this is page1
http://mysite.appspot.com/something/something-else/page1 - page1 also
http://mysite.appspot.com/something/something-else/page2 - page2
http://mysite.appspot.com/something/something-else/pageN - pageN
```

Can I define that with WSGIApplication / app.yaml?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for something like `/page(\d+)?`.

Comment: OK, `(page(\d+))?` works. But I don't like that I get second matched parameter (page1, page2 etc.), 3rd one is what I am looking for (1, 2 etc.). And `def get(self, page_text, page=1):` somehow doesn't return `page` equal to 1 if page wasn't given in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use the same handler regardless of page, you can treat part of the path as your page variable.

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page='page1'):        
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, World! Welcome to %s.' % page)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/something/something-else/', MainPage),
                                    ('/something/something-else/([^/]+)', MainPage)],
                                                                         debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

app.yaml:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /something/something-else/.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

Comment: I didn't know you could specify pieces of the path as params! So cool. Is that documented in the App Engine webapp docs?

Comment: Yeah, I had my 'wow, awesome!' moment on this not too long ago.  I was looking in the documentation for a quote to include in the answer but couldn't find a mention of this specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Since I need to extract page number (N) from 'pageN', I think it would be better to make 'page' as constant part, right?

Comment: Depends on your use case.  It's easy enough to extract 'N' from a 'pageN' string - int(page[4:]).  Reusing the handler makes sense if you'll be generating the page content for each page in a similar manner, otherwise just create more handlers as needed and map them statically.

Comment: Kevin, you scenario will work, I think. But actually I am looking for something like `(page(\d+))?` (that is not fully correct) - i.e. there will only one line at webapp.WSGIApplication, and only integer `(\d+)` will be passed to the handler.

Comment: Regardless of whether you use '([^/]+)' or '(page(\d+))?' you'll have to extract the integer portion.  Also, the first line in webapp.WSGIApplication is required if you want a blank url to match 'page1'.

Comment: Kevin, if I use my code, then (1) I don't need to extract integer, since third parm is already integer (yes, it is actually string, but it is equal to `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` and so on, not `'page1'`, `'page2'`, `'page3'`), (2) there is no need to have first line in webapp, since page part is optional, there is question mark at the end - `(page)?`.